# Change section background colour for each loop in an image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple slider on my home page which loops through different images.

To spice things up, I wonder is it possible to change the `background-color:` value of the `cd-hero` section each time a new image is loaded up? Can I store this in an array so the first image loads a red background and the 2nd image loads blue and so on?

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/12dd5j1s/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');

 //check if a .cd-hero-slider exists in the DOM 
 if ( slidesWrapper.length > 0 ) {
  var primaryNav = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
   sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav'),
   navigationMarker = $('.cd-marker'),
   slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length,
   visibleSlidePosition = 0,
   autoPlayId,
   autoPlayDelay = 5000;

  //upload videos (if not on mobile devices)
  uploadVideo(slidesWrapper);

  //autoplay slider
  setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

  //on mobile - open/close primary navigation clicking/tapping the menu icon
  primaryNav.on('click', function(event){
   if($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
  });
  
  //change visible slide
  sliderNav.on('click', 'li', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var selectedItem = $(this);
   if(!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
    // if it's not already selected
    var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
     activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();
    
    if( activePosition < selectedPosition) {
     nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
    } else {
     prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
    }

    //this is used for the autoplay
    visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

    updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
    updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, selectedPosition+1);
    //reset autoplay
    setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
   }
  });
 }

 function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
   visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
  checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
 }

 function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n){
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
   visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
  checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
 }

 function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
  var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
  navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
  pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');
 }

 function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
  if(wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
   clearInterval(autoPlayId);
   autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function(){autoplaySlider(length)}, delay);
  }
 }

 function autoplaySlider(length) {
  if( visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
   nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
   visibleSlidePosition +=1;
  } else {
   prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
   visibleSlidePosition = 0;
  }
  updateNavigationMarker(navigationMarker, visibleSlidePosition+1);
  updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
 }

 function uploadVideo(container) {
  container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function(){
   var videoWrapper = $(this);
   if( videoWrapper.is(':visible') ) {
    // if visible - we are not on a mobile device 
    var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
     video = $('<video loop><source src="'+videoUrl+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+videoUrl+'.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
    video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
    // play video if first slide
    if(videoWrapper.parent('.cd-bg-video.selected').length > 0) video.get(0).play();
   }
  });
 }

 function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
  //check if a video outside the viewport is playing - if yes, pause it
  var hiddenVideo = hiddenSlide.find('video');
  if( hiddenVideo.length > 0 ) hiddenVideo.get(0).pause();

  //check if the select slide contains a video element - if yes, play the video
  var visibleVideo = container.children('li').eq(n).find('video');
  if( visibleVideo.length > 0 ) visibleVideo.get(0).play();
 }

 function updateNavigationMarker(marker, n) {
  marker.removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-'+n);
 }

 $.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
  //remove all classes starting with 'prefix'
     this.each(function(i, el) {
         var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
             return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
         });
         el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
     });
     return this;
 };
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}






/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #2c343b;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a {
  color: #d44457;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 130%;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #21272c;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

#cd-logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 13px 0 0 5%;
}
#cd-logo img {
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #cd-logo {
    margin: 23px 0 0 5%;
  }
}

.cd-primary-nav {
  /* mobile first - navigation hidden by default, triggered by tap/click on navigation icon */
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../assets/cd-icon-menu.svg") no-repeat center center;
}
.cd-primary-nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.cd-primary-nav ul.is-visible {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.cd-primary-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  background: #21272c;
  border-top: 1px solid #333c44;
  color: #ffffff;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-primary-nav {
    /* reset navigation values */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav ul {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav ul.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  .cd-primary-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .cd-primary-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
    background: transparent;
    padding: .6em 1em;
    border-top: none;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Slider

-------------------------------- */
.cd-hero {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.cd-hero-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cd-hero-slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.cd-hero-slider li.move-left {
  /* slide hidden on the left */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving, .cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* the is-moving class is assigned to the slide which is moving outside the viewport */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-hero-slider {
    height: 680px;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Single slide style

-------------------------------- */
.cd-hero-slider li {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../assets/oneback2.jpg);
}
.cd-hero-slider li:first-of-type {
  background-color: #2c343b;
}
.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #3d4952;
}
.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #5f2322;
}
.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #05132f;
}
.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #2c343b;
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* this padding is used to align the text */
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container {
  /* hide image on mobile device */
  display: none;
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container img {
  position: inherit;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper {
  /* hide video on mobile device */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper video {
  /* you won't see this element in the html, but it will be injected using js */
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-hero-slider h2, .cd-hero-slider p {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0 auto 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.cd-hero-slider h2 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.cd-hero-slider p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2em 1.4em;
  margin-top: .8em;
  background-color: rgba(212, 68, 87, 0.9);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn.secondary {
  background-color: rgba(22, 26, 30, 0.8);
}
.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.no-touch .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn:hover {
  background-color: #d44457;
}
.no-touch .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn.secondary:hover {
  background-color: #161a1e;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
    left: 5%;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 5%;
    left: auto;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2, .cd-hero-slider p {
    max-width: 520px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    padding-top: 220px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2, .cd-hero-slider p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Single slide animation

-------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(40px);
    -o-transform: translateX(40px);
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-half-width {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-40px);
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-half-width {
    /* this is the visible slide */
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .is-moving .cd-half-width {
    /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport 
    wait for the end of the transition on the <li> parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 40px/-40px */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2),
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
    /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:first-of-type,
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    /* this is the visible slide */
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport 
    wait for the end of the transition on the li parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 100px/-100px */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected h2 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected p {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected .cd-btn {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Slider navigation

-------------------------------- */
.cd-slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
.cd-slider-nav nav, .cd-slider-nav ul, .cd-slider-nav li, .cd-slider-nav a {
  height: 100%;
}
.cd-slider-nav nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #d44457;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 currentColor;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}
.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(200%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
  -o-transform: translateX(200%);
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(300%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(300%);
  -o-transform: translateX(300%);
  transform: translateX(300%);
}
.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(400%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(400%);
  -o-transform: translateX(400%);
  transform: translateX(400%);
}
.cd-slider-nav ul::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cd-slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected a {
  color: #2c343b;
}
.no-touch .cd-slider-nav li.selected a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.cd-slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #a8b4be;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-slider-nav a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: url(../assets/cd-icon-navigation.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.no-touch .cd-slider-nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
.cd-slider-nav li:first-of-type a::before {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected:first-of-type a::before {
  background-position: 0 -24px;
}
.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
  background-position: -24px -24px;
}
.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
  background-position: -48px -24px;
}
.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
  background-position: -72px 0;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
  background-position: -72px -24px;
}
.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}
.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
  background-position: -96px -24px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-slider-nav {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav .cd-marker,
  .cd-slider-nav li {
    width: 95px;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav a {
    padding-top: 48px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav a::before {
    top: 18px;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main content

-------------------------------- */
.cd-main-content {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
.cd-main-content p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #999999;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-main-content {
    padding: 3em 0;
  }
  .cd-main-content p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Javascript disabled

-------------------------------- */
.no-js .cd-hero-slider li {
  display: none;
}
.no-js .cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  display: block;
}

.no-js .cd-slider-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-hero">
  <ul class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">
   
   <li class="selected">
    <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=83&txt=1000%C3%97780&w=1000&h=780" alt="tech 1">
    </div> <!-- .cd-full-width -->
   </li>

   <li>
    <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/780/sports" alt="tech 1">
    </div> <!-- .cd-half-width.cd-img-container -->
   </li>

  </ul> <!-- .cd-hero-slider -->

  </section> <!-- .cd-hero -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution to your issue (please see the below fiddle for complete integration):

```
var sectionContainer = $('.cd-hero');
var slideColors = ['red', 'blue'];

function updateBackgroundColor(currentSlideIndex) {
    if(currentSlideIndex < slideColors.length) {
        sectionContainer.css('background-color', slideColors[currentSlideIndex]);
    }
}
```

And then calling `updateBackgroundColor` in the `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` methods with the `n` (index) argument should do the trick.

The array `slideColors` can be added to and the positions in the array will correlate to their respective image positions in your carousel.

In action:

https://jsfiddle.net/12dd5j1s/2/

Note: the initial background-color was set via css

Comment: Wow - fantastic, @roger - thank you so much. I now just need to figure out how to use images instead of colours & I'll be all set.

Answer (score 1):

And below my example. Number of colors in param is independent and for example you can use five color for two slides.

https://jsfiddle.net/h13guumn/

```
var primaryNav = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
    sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav'),
    navigationMarker = $('.cd-marker'),
    slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length,
    visibleSlidePosition = 0,
    autoPlayId,
    autoPlayDelay = 2000,
    backgroundColors = ['FF0000', '00FF00', '0000FF'],
    _backgroundIndex;

function changeBackground() {
    if(backgroundColors && backgroundColors.length > 0) {
        $('.cd-hero-slider').css('background-color', '#'+backgroundColors[_backgroundIndex]);

        if(_backgroundIndex < backgroundColors.length - 1) {
            _backgroundIndex++;
        }
        else {
            _backgroundIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```